# regex allow white space, but do not begin or end with one, and not all white spaces

Tags: regex, re2

I am trying to implement a regex rule that would allow users to enter white spaces, but it should not be all white spaces, nor begin or end with a white space. My research did not yield any workable solution. Currently, my rule looks like this, and I would like to add the white space requirement on top of that:

```
let string_rule = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,16}$";
```

Comment: add some example and your wanted output

Answer (score 0):

let string_rule = "^\S[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,16}\S$";

Comment: OP asked for not ending in a white space. I think you're missing a `^` before your second `\S`.

Comment: there is a syntax error with this error, it resulted an error

Answer (score 0):

you can use following regex:

`^(?:\S.*?\S|\S)$`

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YMd5N6/1)

**Details**

`^`: start of string

`\S.*?\S`: first state which your input have more than 1 character, then its first and last character must exist and not to be spaces

`\S`: second state when your input consists of only one character

`$`: end of string